# onClick Event for DynamicCheckbox ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to ASP.net, predominantly write programs with Access and VB6 and am trying to port something over to ASP.net.  I basically have a program that dynamically creates checkboxes/textboxes and reads in the query values into each textbox.  This park works great but I'm having problems trying to trigger an event whenever the checkbox is checked as I would like for it to do something specific with that textboxes message.  I know how to trigger click events for regular fixed checkboxes but these dynamic ones are driving me crazy because I can't get quite it to work.  I've hacked together some code from different site and this is what I have.  Can anyone help?

The concept here is that the dynamic texboxes will contain toppings for burgers read in from the SQL query (which works), but when the user clicks on the checkbox associated with each textbox, it'll record the value that it's for (like lettuce or tomato).

```
Private Sub Burgers_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Dim myConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxx250\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Burgers\Burgers\App_Data\Burgers Database.accdb;"
    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection(myConnString)
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim strSQL_Count As String
    Dim intSQL_Count As Integer

    strSQL_Count = "SELECT COUNT(*) As Record_Count FROM tblBurgers WHERE Type = 'Topping'"

    Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(strSQL_Count, myConnection)
    Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While myReader.Read

        intSQL_Count = myReader.GetInt32(0)

    End While

    Dim myCommand2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblBurgers", myConnection)
    Dim myReader2 As OleDbDataReader = myCommand2.ExecuteReader()

    Dim i As Integer

    'This automatically loops through the query results, whether it be 1 or 100
    While myReader2.Read

        Dim txt1 = New TextBox()
        Dim chk1 = New CheckBox
        txt1.ID = "txtTextBox" & (i).ToString
        chk1.ID = "chkCheckBox" & (i).ToString
        chk1.AutoPostBack = True

        txt1.Width = 400
        txt1.Text = myReader2.GetString(2)
        txt1.Wrap = True
        txt1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine
        txt1.AutoPostBack = True

        TabContainer1_Toppings_Panel.Controls.Add(chk1)
        TabContainer1_Toppings_Panel.Controls.Add(txt1)

        Dim lt As New Literal()
        lt.Text = "<br />"
        TabContainer1_Toppings_Panel.Controls.Add(lt)

        If IsPostBack = True Then
            RecreateControls("chk", "Checkbox")
            RecreateControls("txt", "Textbox")
        End If

        i = i + 1
    End While

End Sub

Private Function FindOccurence(ByVal substr As String) As Integer

    Dim reqstr As String = Request.Form.ToString()
    Return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) / substr.Length)

End Function

Private Sub RecreateControls(ByVal ctrlPrefix As String, ByVal ctrlType As String)
    Dim ctrls As String() = Request.Form.ToString().Split("&"c)
    Dim cnt As Integer = FindOccurence(ctrlPrefix)

    If cnt > 0 Then
        Dim lt As Literal
        For k As Integer = 1 To cnt
            For i As Integer = 0 To ctrls.Length - 1

                If ctrls(i).Contains((ctrlPrefix & "-") + k.ToString()) Then
                    Dim ctrlName As String = ctrls(i).Split("="c)(0)
                    Dim ctrlValue As String = ctrls(i).Split("="c)(1)

                    'Decode the Value
                    ctrlValue = Server.UrlDecode(ctrlValue)

                    If ctrlType = "TextBox" Then
                        Dim txt As New TextBox()
                        txt.ID = ctrlName
                        txt.Text = ctrlValue
                        TabContainer1_Toppings_Panel.Controls.Add(txt)
                        lt = New Literal()
                        lt.Text = "<br />"
                        TabContainer1_Toppings_Panel.Controls.Add(lt)
                    End If

                    If ctrlType = "Checkbox" Then
                        Dim chk1 As New CheckBox
                        chk1.ID = ctrlName

                        'These msgboxes aren't firing, although post back activity is happening here
                        If chk1.Checked = True Then
                            MsgBox("We have a hit on checked checkbox")
                        ElseIf chk1.Checked = False Then
                            MsgBox("We have a hit on non-checked checkbox")

                        End If

                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If

            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please write the following lines above your lines:

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
```

This is for better code.

What you are searching for is the AddHandler and RemoveHandler statement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

-Variables should always be defined:

```
Dim strSQL_Count As String = String.Empty
    Dim intSQL_Count As Integer = 0
```

-Use methods instead of writing code directly to your click_event, init or whatever method.

-This can be written easier:

```
 Dim txt1 = New TextBox()
        Dim chk1 = New CheckBox
        txt1.ID = "txtTextBox" & (i).ToString
        chk1.ID = "chkCheckBox" & (i).ToString
        chk1.AutoPostBack = True

        txt1.Width = 400
        txt1.Text = myReader2.GetString(2)
        txt1.Wrap = True
        txt1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine
        txt1.AutoPostBack = True

      Dim chk1 As CheckBox = New CheckBox()
      Dim txt1 As TextBox = New TextBox()
      With chk1
       .ID = "chkCheckBox" & (i).ToString
       .AutoPostBack = True
      End With
     With txt1
     ....
    End With
```

If IsPostBack = True Then  not necessary. just write:

```
If IsPostBack Then
```

i = i + 1 not necessary.   just write i+=1

```
If chk1.Checked = True Then
                            MsgBox("We have a hit on checked checkbox")
                        ElseIf chk1.Checked = False Then
                            MsgBox("We have a hit on non-checked checkbox")

                        End If
```

= True is not necessary either. chk1.Checked can be replaced with !chk1.Checked.

Do not use MsgBox. Use `MessageBox.Show("")` instead.